# Core Data NSTableView do not match

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nstableview, osx-mountain-lion

I'm having an issue with Core Data.  I have an Array Controller setup that links the data to an NSTableView.

I have a function that runs code every few seconds and in it I display the list of files

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"File"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

[request setEntity:entity];
NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *fetchedObjects =[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request
                                                              error:&error];

for (NSManagedObject *objectt in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"Object Name: %@", [objectt valueForKey:@"filename"]);
}
NSManagedObject *object = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:index];

NSLog(@"Filename: %@, Index: %ld", [object valueForKey:@"filename"], index);
NSString *imageName = [object valueForKey:@"imageName"];
NSImage *image = [object valueForKey:@"taggedImage"];
```

First time this code is ran the list matches the table columns.   When it's ran again what's fetched from the array controller has changed, but not the tableview.  So it's not in sync anymore.

The values at the same index for the table and array are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you manually checked your `NSArrayController` to see if it is in sync?  That would narrow the question down to is the `NSArrayController` misconfigured or is the NSTableView misconfigured.  Your statement claims you are looking at the `NSArrayController` but when you use the word fetched I worry you are confusing the objects.

Also, is the data in a saved state or still in an unsaved state?  That question also impacts display from the `NSArrayController` and `NSTableView`.

Comment: The array matches the table. The problem may be the fact that I'm using the code NSManagedObject *object = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:index]; index is a value that increments by 1 every time it's ran.  Is there another method I should be using in getting the information?  Is it wrong to access the array directly?

Comment: Nothing wrong with accessing the array directly.  I am not seeing the code that increments that index so I don't understand the relation of the index variable to the table view.  Maybe explain that a bit?

Comment: If it's okay to access the array directly to obtain the information at an index it works fine!  I changed it so it does just that.